# Roof trusses left out in rain, are they still good?

Tags: roof, roofing

I experienced a house fire in May 2015.  The house is undergoing a full gut job.  The roof has to be completely replaced.

Unfortunately, I hired the wrong contractor and they have been taking their sweet time getting anything done.  In October the demolition was done. The house is now just a shell of concrete block; no drywall, no roof.  The roof trusses were delivered in early December and have been sitting outside un-covered since then.

I live in Florida. It doesn't get very cold, but we have had some serious rain recently.  Will the trusses warp? Will there be mold to deal with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this article should give you some answers:

http://www.sbcmag.info/article/2012/truss-storage

In short, it all depends on how the trusses look after the time. The article says that they may be left out for a week max and then should be covered, but any time after that just comes down to what the current weather conditions have done to them.

Comment: That article is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.